# Do tools exist which automatically find copy-and-paste code?

Tags: code-analysis, copy-paste, static-analysis, code-duplication

Are there tools out there which could automatically find copy-and-paste code among a set of files?

I was thinking of writing a script for this, which would just search for equal strings, but such script would find mostly irrelevant equalities. (Such as `private final static ...`).

Comment: Pretty old thread I know, but I was looking for a tool and stumbled across this, I also found that as well as PMD, Resharpers free command line tools offer something called dupFinder for C# and VB.Net code https://www.jetbrains.com/help/resharper/dupFinder.html

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Yes, try the [Copy Paste Detector](https://pmd.github.io/#about).

Comment: Thanks for this one. Just one question I could not solve: How do I exclude certain .cpp files?

Comment: Site responds with 404 not found.

Answer (score 3):

Our [CloneDR](http://www.semanticdesigns.com/Products/Clone) is a tool for finding exact and near-miss blocks of code constructed by copy and paste activities.
It can handle systems of millions of lines of code.

It uses precise language grammars to pick out language structures (identifiers, expressions, statements, blocks, functions, classes, packages, ...) that have been copied, and to determine the points of variation across the sets of clones (any of those structures can be parameters!)

CloneDR operates on a wide variety of languages: C, C++, C#, Java, PHP, COBOL, Python, Ada, Fortran, EGL and visual basic (VBScript, VB6, VB.net).

The website has a number of sample clone detection reports from a variety of those languages.

This product is available for evaluation on http://www.semanticdesigns.com. Other open source alternatives are [Simian](http://www.harukizaemon.com/simian/) and [PMD CPD](http://pmd.sourceforge.net/cpd.html)

Answer (score 2):

http://patterninsight.com/products/cp-miner.php

Related paper - http://citeseerx.ist.psu.edu/viewdoc/summary?doi=10.1.1.123.113

Answer (score 1):

[CloneDigger](http://clonedigger.sourceforge.net/) for Python and Java.