# Find copy-and-paste code - for bash / shell script

Tags: bash

I have a bash project, which consists a dozen files. There are some copy paste between the files (and inside one files also).

So, is there a copy paste detector for bash / shell scripts or at least for plain text?

---

Copy paste detector, like this, just for shell script: http://pmd.sourceforge.net/pmd-5.1.0/cpd.html

Similar question for java: [Do tools exist which automatically find copy-and-paste code?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2427939/do-tools-exist-which-automatically-find-copy-and-paste-code)

Comment: What do you mean with "copy paste detector"?

Comment: What do you mean by _'some copy paste between the files'_ ?

Comment: For Perl, there is [Code::CutNPaste](http://p3rl.org/Code::CutNPaste). Maybe you can get some inspiration from it.

Comment: [checkstyle?](http://checkstyle.sourceforge.net/config_duplicates.html)

Comment: I am surprised how few people know what is a copy paste detector (and maybe downvote for that reason)

Comment: Requests for tool recommendations are explicitly off-topic on StackOverflow, so guessing that downvotes are out of ignorance is perhaps ill-founded. (That said, I've never heard of duplicate code detection tools being called "copy paste detectors").

Comment: Is there a similar site to migrate the question to?

Answer (score 0):

This is what [comm](http://ss64.com/bash/comm.html) is for:

```
comm -12 <(sort file1.txt) <(sort file2.txt)
```

Answer (score 0):

I've been searching for this myself. Here are some of the results I've found that either claim they do plain text, or someone else claims they do plain text.

[MOSS](http://theory.stanford.edu/~aiken/moss/)

Clone Dr

Simian

[Near Dup](http://www.softcorporation.com/products/neardup/)

I've also run into some others, such as DuDe (exists several places) and CCfinder but I can't get either of them to compile.

I only post anonymously, so I don't have enough rep to post more than two links, sorry.

Edit: Atomiq worked for me on plain text, that will probably be my go to now